# How to kill Freestyle 'scribbles' and 'flecks'?

Tags: freestyle

Here's a technical model I tidied up topologically. I want Freestyle line diagrams out of it. But I'm getting problems.
[image: Digital Matter G70 Freestyle oddities]

1. Overprinted lines/"scribbles". There are two line styles in operation. They're being applied to the same model topology. But when rendered there are numerous 'over-draws', like someone's scribbled over the same line but slightly differently.
2. Transparency. This model is in three parts - lid, base, cable socket, all solid. But base lines the lid should be hiding are showing through.
3. "Flecks". Short lines that are neither marked as Freestyle edges nor creases are being randomly placed on the detail (thin) strokes.
4. Broken lines. Lines marked with Freestyle edges occasionally have discontinuous breaks.

I'm going a little nuts trying to figure out what settings do which in Freestyle. File available for download:
[image]

Notes:

**Edge Detection > Crease Angle:** 15°; Culling +  Face smoothness enabled

**Lineset: Outline (Thick, Black): Edge Type > Inclusive Logical OR** - Silhouette; Crease

**Lineset: Detail (Thin, Charcoal): Edge Type > Inclusive OR** - Edge Mark

If anyone could spot that critical checkbox or two of the several billion in Blender that I need to check, please let me know :/

Comment: Would you mind marking up your model explicitly for illustration, or do you want line-sets that will generalize to anything you throw at them?

Comment: MArk up the model, or mark up the illustration?

Comment: The model. The contours are very smooth, ambiguous for crease-detection. You could explicitly mark Freestyle edges on the model, or, say, boundaries between materials..

Comment: The model is freestyle-marked, particularly along curved edges. You can download the .blend file above and see or yourself. In fact, one of the problems is that the deliberately-placed Freestyle lines are broken, when they should be contiguous. I'm prepping an animated GIF indicating the various problems.

Comment: Illustration updated.